# Why does Linux boot with a few dentries initialized for root directory "/"

Tags: linux, filesystems, linux-kernel, vfs

I am playing around Linux kernel code, especially the file system part. I've found that when the kernel boots, a few of dentry objects are allocated for root directory "/". Why dose it need to allocate multiple copies of root directory in RAM? Moreover, since it seems that the dcache (dentry cache, essentially a big hash table) is using a hash function H(parent_dentry_address, name_hash) to calculate the bucket a dentry resisted in. Does it means that each root dentry "/" makes a different dentry mapping to the hash bucket in dcache?

Btw, the above behaviors were observed on Linux-3.3.0-rc4.

Comment: It would help if you linked to the code you are talking about, using e.g. http://lxr.linux.no/

Comment: I haven't found where causes this problem yet. I only added few printk in __d_alloc() to print out the dentry->d_name.name and dentry's pointer address. It shows that when Linux boots, a few "/" dentries with different pointers are allocated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to close my eyes and not look at any code and just blurt out, could this possibly be the result of mounting `/` over `/`, and more than once?

If you mount something over `/`, the underlyling `/` cannot just go away  because it can be exposed by an umount.

Comment: This is more than likely the cause of what the OP is seeing.

Answer (score 1):

Read Documentation/initrd.txt from the kernel source to see what's happening on bootstrapping:

```
When using initrd, the system typically boots as follows:

  1) the boot loader loads the kernel and the initial RAM disk
  2) the kernel converts initrd into a "normal" RAM disk and
     frees the memory used by initrd
  3) if the root device is not /dev/ram0, the old (deprecated)
     change_root procedure is followed. see the "Obsolete root change
     mechanism" section below.
  4) root device is mounted. if it is /dev/ram0, the initrd image is
     then mounted as root
  5) /sbin/init is executed (this can be any valid executable, including
     shell scripts; it is run with uid 0 and can do basically everything
     init can do).
  6) init mounts the "real" root file system
  7) init places the root file system at the root directory using the
     pivot_root system call
  8) init execs the /sbin/init on the new root filesystem, performing
     the usual boot sequence
  9) the initrd file system is removed

Note that changing the root directory does not involve unmounting it.
It is therefore possible to leave processes running on initrd during that
procedure. Also note that file systems mounted under initrd continue to
be accessible.
```

I hope that this answers to the question why does the kernel allocate a few dentries for "/"

Answer (score 0):

In kernel there are two type '/',one for process root dir and other is file system root dir.

When file system register and mounted, it will first alloc a dentry for mount root as the entry of this file system,normally this dentry use the '/' name.RAM fs like proc/devtmpfs... mounted inner kernel,so there will be several dentry with the same name '/'.